# Capture photo or video cordova

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova, video

I'm trying to allow the user to capture a photo or a video within one function (i.e on the device the camera allows for a photo or video to be taken)

The problem I have is that using naviagor.device.capture.captureVideo only takes videos, I have tried changing the sourceType to 2 but that is not making any difference. As it stands this code only allows for a video to be taken and I want the user to be able to take a photo or a video.

```
function takeVideo(){
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType : 2,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        correctOrientation: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        createFileEntry(fileURI);
        toast("Video taken woop woop");
        console.log(imageData);
        saveImageToPhone(imageData, success, error);
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('No photo taken.');
    };
}
```

Comment: I believe you cannot do this. You have to force the user from within your application to choose either to capture a video or a photo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I did assume that was the case but wanted to make sure.